# JS Page Searcher

Tags: javascript

I need to bruteforce through pages and check it's contents for certain text.

ie. I have page: http://example.whatever/internet?ip=$4.2$$.$$6.$$$ and those dollar signs, are missing numbers. I need to go through all of existing combinations untill 404 - Page not found text isn't present on that page anymore (it's not an error code, that gets returned, just the text.)

I also need to be able to use it when there is login required to access the pages, and I have the necessary access, that's why I suggest JS to be used in this, and not server side script, like PHP or Python.

Edit 1: In case you want to complain, that this is not a question, I'm asking how to do it. And if you don't have the balls (or whatever it is you have or don't have) to comment bellow, why you did press that arrow down next to this question, so we can resolve it, please don't do it. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: this is not a question...

Comment: @JuniusRendel I'm asking how to do it. I thought that much is obvious... Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for this. You could login then iterate through pages until you find a non-404 page.

Comment: Thanks! Will look into it, for now I'm not marking this as accepted answer, I hope you understand.

Comment: Can it show a frame of the page (like a browser), so I can login? The page uses reCaptcha to block bots on login, so I need to manually login, and then let the bot do It's thing.

Comment: Sorry, crawler is more accurate in this case.

Comment: PhantomJS allows you to screenshot the current page that it is on. You could screenshot the page with the captcha, look at the screenshot yourself and manually input the captcha for PhantomJS to process. Should work if you only need to login once. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452131/is-there-a-way-to-read-user-input-from-keybord-for-phantomjs

Comment: That's unfortuantely not possible, as I said, page uses reCaptcha as login bot protection, and that's actually JS Rendered check-box. Not only that, but it monitors mouse movement on the page, and it (the cursor) jumping from box to box in less then a milisecond would surely trigger it's safe captcha, which is usually "Select pictures with traffic signs" or something simmillar, so I need to be able to interact with the page directly. If PhantomJS can't do that, then it can't be used in my use case...

Comment: Another option is to login on your browser, lookup the cookie for the site and then have Phantom.js use that cookie. Here is a question which covers how that is done using addCookie: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221030/how-to-use-phantomjs-cookie-api

Comment: Will look into that. But this one should work. Marking as accepted answer.